# Is this considered a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

```
You have 100 popsicle sticks each with a different number on them and a group
of 100 students. You shuffle the sticks and hand them out to each student so 
that every student has a different numbered popsicle stick. Let F(x) denote 
the relationship that maps the student's to the sticks.
```

Is F(x) a function?

I said no, because a function cannot be random, it has to have a set output given the input. Although this is bijective, it is still not a function. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: The answer below (by Henry W) is correct assuming any specific chosen random distribution of sticks. But note that there are 100! different possible functions...

Answer (score 2):

A function is left-total and many-to-one

Left-total: Every student is assigned a stick

Many-to-one: Each student is assigned only one stick.

Hence $F$ is a function.